# How to upload an Android Wear screenshot to the play store?

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

How do I upload an Android Wear screenshot to the play store? There isn't a Wear category, and the Phone category wouldn't accept a square shaped screenshot.

*Just realized it's not the aspect ratio. But the resolution. The screenshot from my watch is 280x280, while the Play Store need screenshots to be at least 320px wide.*

Comment: If you look at any postings of Android Wear Apps on the Play store, you will notice that most developers have edited the screenshot and made it larger (by adding a watch outline, company logo, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized it's not the aspect ratio. But the resolution. The screenshot from my watch is 280x280, while the Play Store need screenshots to be at least 320px wide.

Comment: This is not an answer: You should edit it to your own question.